# Can't access random web pages on my MacBook Pro 2012?

Tags: mac, browser, internet-connection

Sometimes I can't access random web pages. The page simply doesn't load. If I wait for around a minute doing nothing, it will load. It happens very random and very intermittent. Sometimes it starts when I try to access `youtube.com` or `cnn.com`. When it starts, it happens once in a minute or once in 5 minutes for random web pages.

But if I am downloading something, the download continues without any interruption. And also I am able to ping the address I can't browse. Then if I wait for around a minute, everything starts to work fine at the browser side also.

I have tried a lot of different browsers. I have tried changing my DNS servers to Google's public DNS servers. Using a cable instead of the wireless connection doesn't work either. No one else in the network has this problem, but me. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was acwebsecagent process running in the background causing the problem. It was installed with Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.